# Calendar List - remove links to other views and "find an item" search box

Tags: list, search, 2016, navigation, calendar

I have a list of calendar events and at the top of the page is a horizontal row of links to other calendar views and a search box to "find an item". How do I remove these?

Below is a screenshot of what I need to remove, the items "Crescent Intranet" and "Sales" are on the line of links, and the "Find an item" box to the right of the list of views.

[image]

Comment: Please post a screenshot of what functionality you are referring to.  Also, since capabilities can vary greatly from one version of SharePoint to the next and from on-premises to Online, please include this information in your question.

Answer (score -1):

**"Find an Item" box**:  To hide this, go up to the Gear icon at the top of the page, and choose "Edit Page" to put the page into edit mode.  Once in edit mode, the upper-right-hand corner of the List will have a little drop-down arrow.  When you click that arrow, you can choose the option to "Edit Web Part".
This will open the web part properties pane on the right-hand side of the page. From there List views go to the Miscellaneous section. From there Uncheck the checkbox "Display search box".  Then click the "OK" button at the bottom of the properties pane.

**Top Links**:  There is no built-in setting to "hide" or "turn off" this set of links, but if you hit the "Edit Link" pencil icon next to those links, you have the ability to Delete each one manually.